# C# Access Denied when requesting using .NET 6

Tags: c#-6.0

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem with this error?
Setting also with User-Agent doesn't fix the problem.
I'm using .NET 6

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;somesite&#46;com&#47;api&#47;1&#46;0&#47;user&#47;devices&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;4eb78aca&#46;1650665931&#46;11b07677
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Also I tried setting this options as well

```
public static HttpClient Client { get; set; } = new(
        new HttpClientHandler { 
            Proxy = null,
            UseProxy = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true
       }, true);

ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
        //// save bandwidth before sending huge object for post and put request to ensure remote end point is up and running.
        //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Is this someting with this TLS?
[image]

Comment: What is it and what makes you think it should work? Can you succeed with the request in some other way? Or with a different version of .NET?

Comment: Hi. I failed also with any request only in this specific site that I've been trying.
I haven't tested yet with lower version. I'll try it now first with 5.0

Comment: Same as well with 5.0

Comment: Still can't fix this problem :( I tried other version as well

Comment: Can you access that site at all, in any way, from a browser, using `curl`, anything? I assume it's not called `http://www.somesite.com/api/1.0/user/devices?`, or are you really trying to access that URL?

Comment: Hello. Yes I can access it on browser and it's just giving of course the error. Also in python I don't have any problem at all and also postman. Only with C# I don't know why but I tried also 3.1-6.0

Comment: Hello. Yes I'm trying to request with that URL and return all devices. 

I can access it on browser and it's just giving of course the error since I have to provide the authentication. Also in python I don't have any problem at all and also postman. Only with C# I don't know why but I tried also 3.1-6.0

Comment: When I print out the response headers, The server is "AKamaiGHost".
I still can't find any solution because this might be blocking me from requesting